# No funciona el autocompletado de Laravel en Sublime Text en Windows 10

Tags: windows, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Hola presento un pequeño problema con este editor, en `ubuntu` lo usaba y el auto completado de `laravel` era exitoso aparte de autocompletarme el codigo me hacía el llamado de las `class` en use `/iluminate/response;`

No tenia que estar escribiendo tanto, resulta que como tengo `windows 10` ahora lo instale pero nada, no me hace nada, ahorita tengo instalado `atom` pero me consume mucha ram y uso de cpu, alguno podria ayudarme para el autocompletado de `laravel` en `sublimetext`.

Comment: ¿De casualidad tenías algún plugin en el sublime text de ubuntu?

Comment: no eran los mismos plugins no tenia otro diferente al que instale en windows los mismo Solo instale en ubuntu como windows SublimeCodeintel y phpintel y con esos dos en ubuntu el sublime me funcionaba perfecto pero en windows no corre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes instalar los snippets de Laravel que aparecen como **Laravel 4 Snippets** en el Package Control de Sublime.
O tambien puedes usar **ide-helper** [Ide helper laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

Nota: para usar ide-helper debes tener SublimeCodeIntel instalado en el editor.

Finalmente si quieres obtener el autocompletado de los namespace, puedes instalar **PHPCompanion**.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda..!